# tmap talend NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, talend

I'm trying to read two csv's into my SQL Server.  Getting `NullPointerException` even though I'm allowing nullables and checking null each time.  When debugging, it appears that the null check expression is evaluating to the FALSE condition every time, even when the string is null.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSN8T.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWheG.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8R1L.png]

Here's an example of my null check:

```
( row2.Acq_date.equals(null) || row2.Acq_date.equals("") || 
row2.Acq_date == null ) ? null : (int) 
TalendDate.diffDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(),row2.Acq_date,"MM")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do null checking like this `row2.Acq_date.equals(null)`.
This is the correct way : `row2.Acq_date == null` (which you actually included in your test, only doing it after testing `row2.Acq_date.equals(null)` is too late, since that is the part throwing the `NullPointerException`).

Here's the correct way :

```
( row2.Acq_date == null ? null : (int) 
TalendDate.diffDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(),row2.Acq_date,"MM")
```

Based on your comment, `row2.Acq_date` is of type date, which you can read directly from your file using the appropriate date format. If the column is empty (or contains whitespaces) in your file, Talend returns a null date, which is handled by the above test.

Comment: I have row2.Acq_date coming in as a date... do you think its more advisable to input as string, then parse to date, as you're suggesting here?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed row2.Acq_date was of type string since you were testing against an empty string; no need to read it as string, I've updated my answer :)